# Bootstrap gallery won't change image after implemented into site

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My image gallery, won't change foxus images, despite working fine on bootsnipp, where I got it.

Here is the [site, "live"](http://blakehamilton.design/gallery.html)

here is the [bootsnipp I got.](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/WPmbr)

and the source can be found on github at /blakeaham/dansite1

Details:  I put the js from the bootsnipp into the gallery.html, at the bottom, but I tried moving it to the top, and linking it as a separate file, which doesn't help,

Comment: Your site reports `jQuery is not defined`, and I don't see it in your `<head>`. Are you sure you have included jQuery?

Comment: It's at the bottom of the page, and I had it commented out. Jeesh, thanks a million. 

Weird thing is, that fixes the 'next' and 'previous' functions but not clicking on another image. 

I guess it works halfway now, at least. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Remember that the DOM is read **sequentially*, so your image clicks not working is probably because they're using jQuery higher up in your DOM than when you reference jQuery. It's recommended to include jQuery in your `<head>` to ensure that it loads before any actual jQuery code (though you still have to watch for dependencies). You can always debug your site and spot the error messages in your Developer Console by pressing F12 :)

Comment: Thank you. Man, it's embarrassing to need to be saved from such careless mistakes. Thank you again, I'm off to get myself a refresher on devtools debugging, so I don't need rescue again for something like this. Thanks again, though, kind stranger.

Comment: No problem, though I'll go ahead and copy these comments as an answer so you can go ahead and close this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your site reports jQuery is not defined. Looking through your source code, you appear to have commented it out.

Also, remember that the DOM is read **sequentially**, so your image clicks not working is probably because they're using jQuery higher up in your DOM than when you reference jQuery.

It's recommended to include jQuery in your `<head>` to ensure that it loads before any actual jQuery code (though you still have to watch for dependencies).

Don't forget that you can always debug your site and spot the error messages in your Developer Console by pressing F12 :)

Hope this helps! :)